# What is the recommended way to write to Splunk using Log4J

Tags: log4j, splunk

What is the recommended way to write to Splunk using Log4J? And is there any official documentation on it such as what the log4j config file should look like?

If it matters, my source is a MuleSoft/Java 8 application.

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation can be found here: https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/java/logging-java/ but you may want to check this project out, *Splunk Logging for Java*: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging

It enables you to log events to HTTP Event Collector or to a TCP input on a Splunk Enterprise instance. It also supports the Log4j logging framework

Within the github project, under *splunk-library-javalogging/src/test/resources/* there are some config file examples

Answer (score -1):

As @[Honky Donkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10829300/honky-donkey) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897449/4418), you *can* setup direct logging to the [HTTP Event Collector](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Data/HECExamples).

However, that's *probably* not the best idea - unless you're *also* logging to local disk.

Why is it not a good idea? Because if you're *only* logging to the HEC, you ***must*** have Splunk up and running and configured to receive data from your app (including any requisite HEC tokens) to see any logs your app may generate.

What happens when Splunk is down? Or not otherwise unavailable?

Will your app queue logs until it's available again? How long can it queue? What will happen to logs it *can **not*** queue?

What happens if management decides to change from [Splunk](https://splunk.com) to [ELK Stack](https://elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) or [Scalyr](https://scalyr.com)?

Always log to local disk.

***Offer*** to log elsehwere/elsehow - but don't ***only*** "log to Splunk": you never know what may change down the road.

Comment: Log4J already handles all of that with a simple configuration file.